# Set text box value in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word 2010 form template with various text boxes, combo lists and radio buttons.  I wish to take the value from one text box and insert it as the value of another text box when a Save button is invoked.  I have extracted the value from the source text box with the code below but how do I then insert it as the value of the target text box?  I have tried a few things including the reverse of the code below but so far without success.

```
srp = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("RPI").Item(1).Range.Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Range.Text` property is read/write. So you use the exact reversal of the code you have.

```
srp = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("RPI").Item(1).Range.Text  ' Read
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("SRP").Item(1).Range.Text = srp  ' Write
```

Comment: thanks I thought I tried this but then noticed I had a typing error!!!!!!  Thanks again